# Почему не получается назначить класс из двух слов?

Tags: javascript, html

Почему не могу назначить класс из двух слов? Вот так не работает, В js все меняется, а HTML остается прежний

```
function changeTextDifferences(elOn, parent) {
    elOn.className = 'name on'
    var ulCompany = parent.children[0]
    for (var j = 0; j < ulCompany.children.length; j++) {
        if (ulCompany.children[j].className == 'name on') ulCompany.children[j].className = 'name off'
    }
}
```

А вот так все ок

```
function changeTextDifferences(elOn, parent) {
    var ulCompany = parent.children[0]
    for (var j = 0; j < ulCompany.children.length; j++) {
        if (ulCompany.children[j].className == 'name on') {
            ulCompany.children[j].className = 'name off'
            elOn.className = 'name on'
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zow, сколько можно менять вопрос?? Я два раза писал ответ, один раз запостил и стер его!

Comment: Замени пробелы символом подчёркивания, _ могут с этим быть проблемы.

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, прости, да не надо было стирать. Я бы все понял

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что именно должно происходить?

Насколько понял - elOn - это children для parent. В первом случае - вы ему делаете `name on`, а затем в цикле возвращаете ему `name off`. При этом текущий элемент с `name on` остался без изменений.

Если правильно понял, то в некоторых случаях код будет работать - если по дефолту задать `nmae on`, например, для первого элемента, то по мере движения от начала к концу все будет работать. Но стоит только двинуться назад - все сломается.

А во втором примере - вы сначала сбрасываете `name on` и только потом добавляете элементу elOn класс `name on`. Соответственно все работает так, как надо.

Чтобы работало в первом случае - вставьте проверку в замене классов в цикле на равенство элементу elOn. Т.е. если проверяемый элемент равен elOn, то ему класс не сбрасывать (мы ему только что установили), цикл пойдет дальше и сбросит класс уже у желаемого элемента.